# Finding elements with one class and without another class

Tags: jquery

Is there an elegant way with jQuery to find elements that have class A and don't have class B, something like

```
$('#canvas .A !.B').each(functon() {
          do something
});
```

I'm pretty sure that's not going to work, but that's the idea.

I know I could do

```
$('#canvas .A').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('B'){
          do something
    }
});
```

but that feel really clunky.

Thanks

Comment: Even if the syntax were correct, you selector isn't going to work as you've used a space, so you'd be (at best) selecting elements without class `B` that are ancestors of an element of class `A`.

Comment: elements that have class a not b or elements that does not contain an element with class A and not B?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#canvas .A').not(".B").each(functon() {
          do something
});
```

reference **[not](http://api.jquery.com/not/)**

Comment: Alternatively written `$("#canvas .A:not(.B)")`

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery you can:

`$(".classA").not(".classB");`

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this within a single selector, such as:

```
$('#canvas .A:not(.B)').each(function() {
    // console.log($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that. You can either use [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector  or [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) of jquery.

```
$('#canvas .A:not(.B)').each(functon() {
          do something
});
```

Or

```
$('#canvas .A').not(".B").each(functon() {
              do something
    });
```

Comment: Both are missing closing quotes, and have misspelled "function"